# How to remove issue link from issue links (Atlassian Jira) with Atlassian C# SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, jira

I am using atlassian jira SDK (ver 11). I need to remove the link from the link list.
I'm connect to Jira, getting a list of links:

```
IEnumerable<IssueLink> links = await issue.GetIssueLinksAcync();
```

However, I could not find a way to remove the link from the given list. Tell me how to do it?